# JavaScript only works if the script is placed below the element with the used ID?

Tags: javascript

Why must scripts be placed under the element with the used ID?

This didn't work

```
<script>
    var test = document.getElementById("test");
    test.addEventListener("click", function(){
        alert("It works!");
    });
</script>
<input type="button" id="test">
```

This too didn't work

```
<head>
    <script>
        var test = document.getElementById("test");
        test.addEventListener("click", function(){
            alert("It works!");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="test">
</body>
```

The only one I can make it works is to do this:

```
<input type="button" id="test">
<script>
    var test = document.getElementById("test");
    test.addEventListener("click", function(){
        alert("It works!");
    });
</script>
```

It didn't work too if I placed that script in external js file. Even if I use this

```
if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    var test = document.getElementById("test");
    test.addEventListener("click", function(){
        alert("It works!");
    })
}
```

What did I miss there?

Comment: Your `readyState` only evaluates once, unless it's executed after the document is ready, it won't work the way you expect. I'm not sure what the question is--you can't reference an element that doesn't exist, which explains all the other results, and you can't only test once (using this mechanism) and expect it to always be complete.

Comment: (It's interesting that the higher-ranked users answered completely and the lower-ranked users did not. Not explaining why `readyState` *doesn't* work, IMO, isn't a complete answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.readyState` will return false when executed before the DOM is ready. And you're only doing it once and never try again, so it'll never work. You want the `document.onload` event:

```
// Always wrap your JS files with a self invoking function.
// It prevents variables leaking onto the global state.
(function() {

    // Wait until document fires 'load' event, and call the passed function
    //                              vvvvvvvvvv
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        // Will only be called *after* document is loaded.
        var test = document.getElementById("test");
        test.addEventListener("click", function(){
            alert("It works!");
        });
    });

})();
```

### Some points

- Wrapping all of your files with self invoking functions like in my example is a general good practice to follow. It makes sure that variables defined inside don't leak to the outside.
- Use `window.addEventListener()` and not `document.onload =`, because the former allows you to attached multiple handlers to be called when the document is ready, and the latter only allows one (and will silently override the previous one if you have several).

Comment: I appreiate the valuable informations you gave. But, `document.addEventListener` doesnt works. It works when i changed it to `window.addEventListener`. Could you tell me why?

Comment: @BagolDaplun You are correct. It seems as though `document` doesn't fire the `load` event, but `window` does.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the way JavaScript works. It can't access DOM elements that haven't been created yet, and they are created from top to bottom.

One of the easiest ways to resolve this cleanly is to use an .onload handler:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var test = document.getElementById("test");
    test.addEventListener("click", function(){
        alert("It works!");
    });
};
```

If you're using jQuery, the standard approach is to use a document ready handler:

```
$(function() {
    var test = document.getElementById("test");
    test.addEventListener("click", function(){
        alert("It works!");
    });
});
```

The reason your last attempt didn't work is that if `document.readyState` is not `complete` at the moment that code is reached (as it would not be), then the contents of  that `if` block will be skipped entirely, never to be seen again.

Comment: hah literally the same answer and you beat me by 7 seconds :P

Comment: @JoshuaOhana Yes, but unfortunately, you both skipped the `readyState` part of the question, which IMO is an important part of what the OP isn't understanding.

Comment: @DaveNewton Looks like the downvote bandit hit four out of six of the answers here.

Comment: @JLRishe IMO the other answers actually deserved downvotes (although I didn't), I tend up upvote good answers rather than downvote bad ones. Which is wrong, but it's how I'm built. After the edit I thought yours was fine.

Comment: @JLRishe I'm guessing it's about the `.onload` (as opposed to `.addEventListener()`), that's the only thing mine and Arun's have in common (which were the answers not downvoted)

Answer (score 2):

it is because when your script is executed the target element `test` is not yet added to the dom so `document.getElementById("test")` will return `null`.

`document.readyState === 'complete'` also won't work because when this is executed the dom parsing is not yet completed.

What you can do is to use an window load event handler and execute your script in that

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var test = document.getElementById("test");
    test.addEventListener("click", function(){
        alert("It works!");
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the element doesn't exist until you create it, and you can't get it until then. What you can do in an external file is attach a function to window.onload, as in:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var test = document.getElementById("test");
    test.addEventListener("click", function(){
       alert("It works!");
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

when you write script before element then script not find the element and 
when you write element before script then script find element and it's run.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called myScript.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#test").click(function()}
alert("It works!");
});

});
```

In HTML file called index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='myScript.js'>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="test">
</body>
</html>
```

There ya go, as simple as that !

Answer (score -1):

When you use javascript, always define at the end of the body tag, The reason is quite simple. For example lets take your first code. You try to add an addevenlistener to the button, but the script will run first before the html code. So it doesn't find the element, because it isn't created yet. That's why when you use javascript, always put it at the end of the body tag.

Comment: That's not the most important reason to put the JS at the bottom of the page, though. If the JS is written *correctly* you can put it at the top, the middle, or anywhere else, and it'll work--but it introduces another issue.

Comment: This is incorrect. It's OK or good sometimes to put JS at the bottom of the page, othertimes it's better/necessary to put it at the top.